# Return a list of Facebook friends in Java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How would I get a list of friends that like a Facebook user post. I tried this code:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String accessToken = "EAACEdEoseZBhf0e4WXHuNaItvLeoAZD";
    FacebookClient fbclient = new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken);
    Connection<Post> result = fbclient.fetchConnection("me/feed", Post.class);
    int counter = 0;
    for (List<Post> page : result) {
        for (Post aPost : page) {
            Date time = aPost.getCreatedTime();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -10);
            Date db = c.getTime();
            {
                if (!time.before(db)) {
                    System.out.println("created time     " + time + "\r\n");
                    System.out.println("Id Poste: fb.com/" + aPost.getId() + "\r\n");
                    System.out.println(" L(userx)    " + aPost.getLikes());
                    counter++;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("date hors période" + "\r\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the result of the list of like is:

> Likes[data=[NamedFacebookType[id=758248010897019 metadata=null name=Toka Ep Bouzidi type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=836615436419028 metadata=null name=Basma Youssfi type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=200283693703077 metadata=null name=Sahar Hmidet type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=1589600437936215 metadata=null name=Fifi Daly Omm Omar type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=2285678608326303 metadata=null name=Rà Nou type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=149760905397346 metadata=null name=Awatef Cherif type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=197868283998495 metadata=null name=Samar Maamouri type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=191663454652822 metadata=null name=Ben Ali Fatma Benali type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=1594576777456573 metadata=null name=Rania Trigui type=null], NamedFacebookType[id=10204633957434960 metadata=null name=Gasmi Ghassen type=null]] totalCount=0]

===================================

I need it to return the names of the user's friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Id Poste: fb.com/" + aPost.getLikes() + "\r\n");
```

[Post.getLikes()](http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/Post.html#getLikes--)
will return an Object of Type [Post.like()](http://restfb.com/javadoc/com/restfb/types/Likes.html) that turns into "Object-gibberish" when trying to be printed. For the Like-count use Post.getLikeCount() [can't like source due to low rep, sorry]

For a more detailed answer, please specify your question a bit. What should the Output look like?

Comment: I want the output look like this:                                                                                created time:   Sat Jun 03 21:19:58 CEST 2017
Id Poste:          fb.com/1562752627337463_1944745292471526
liste of friends:                                                                          
Esmeralda Sagittaire
Ben Ali Fatma Benali
Mouna Amor
Hala Ben Mouhamed
Awatef Cherif
Safa Chebbi